# enum's component to be used as an array index

Tags: c, enums

I am new to programming. I have this requirement. I have defined an enum in a header file like:

```
typedef enum test_val
{ 
   a,
   b,
   c
};
```

Now I have defined a global array:

```
int setup[rows][c];
```

`row` is defined using `#define row 10`. 
Now when I use this array in the .c file, it throws an error showing:

> nothing known about c, undeclared in abc.c

So, what am I missing?

Comment: Did you include that header in abc.c?

Comment: Try removing that unnecessary `typedef` behind that `enum` declaration, since you aren't specifying any alias afterwards for a type definition; although this shouldn't really matter, it should work anyway.

Comment: My psychic powers tell me you are using Turbo C. Is that correct ? If yes, I suppose that Turbo C just doesn't support using enum values as array size in declarations.